# Ubuntu CLI, new path for PHP and php.ini

Tags: php, ubuntu, localhost, apache2

Currently my Ubuntu PHP CLI is using: `/opt/lampp/bin/php` and  `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`.

I plan to remove LAMP and continue to use /etc/php/7.2/apache2/ .

Should I change(and how to change) PHP CLI to using: `/usr/bin/php7.2` and `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini` ?

```
ribe@ideapad:~$ php --ini
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 320151012.
The Zend Engine API version 320170718 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Derick Rethans at https://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of Xdebug.

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/lampp/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

ribe@ideapad:~$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php
     (this is symlink to lamp php: 
      ribe@ideapad:/usr/local/bin$ readlink -e php
                   /opt/lampp/bin/php-7.2.6
     )
```

Comment: Have tried removing symlink and create new symlink to /usr/bin/php7.2

Comment: I was thinking to make PHP CLI to use directly php7.2 , and remove whole lamp and the symlink too.